# Matlab: From Disparity Map to 3D coordinates

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, homography, disparity-mapping, warp

I copied the matlab code from: http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/vision/ug/stereo-image-rectification.html
I can compute the 3D coordinates but I am not sure if it is the correct one.

Starting from the disparity map and calculating the 3D coordinates, how do we take into account of the warping `tform1` and `tform2`?

Comment: Tell us more. Elaborate more on what you tried, what you get and show us your doubts. This may be a very interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using uncalibrated cameras. In this case you can get up-to-scale reconstruction, but if you want the 3D points in world units, you would need to know actual distances to some points in the world.

I think you would be better off calibrating your stereo system.  Please see this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-vision.html).